# System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "employee" to type 'Boolean' is not valid.'

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

The form I created pops up but when I click on the open button this error occurs. The error directs me to sqlConn.ConnectionString , So any insights with regards to the problem is really helpful.

```
     Private Sub updateTable()

    sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";" + "user id =" = username + ";" _
    + "password= " + password + ";" + "database" = database

    sqlConn.Open()

        sqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT * From employee.employee"

        sqlRd = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader
        sqlDt.Load(sqlRd)
        sqlRd.Close()
        sqlConn.Close()
        DataGridView1.DataSource = sqlDt

End Sub
```

Comment: Debug your code. You should already done so. What line is the exception thrown on? Why are you trying to convert a `String` to a `Boolean` in the first place? Note that you aren't necessarily doing it explicitly.

Comment: What is `employee.employee`? Do you have a schema named `employee`? If not, what exactly are you qualifying? You select from a table, not a column. EDIT: just realised this is for MySQL rather than SQL Server. I don't use that much so maybe my comment isn;t applicable. Then again, maybe it is.

Comment: I already debugged my code still the same,  "database" = database is where the exception being thrown, database = "employee" , employee being my schema. employee.employee calls out my schema and the table. Basically  I want to open what's inside my database EDIT: I'm new with c# or programming so I'm trying to understand what went wrong here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just didn't actually read your code properly, seeing what you expected to see rather than what's actually there. This:

```vb
sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";" + "user id =" = username + ";" _
+ "password= " + password + ";" + "database" = database
```

is wrong for multiple reasons. What you actually meant to write was this:

```vb
sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" + server + ";" + "user id =" + username + ";" _
+ "password= " + password + ";" + "database=" + database
```

Notice that there were three mistakes in your code. You need to be much more careful and especially when you know specifically that that is the line in error.

That said, there are multiple ways that that code could be improved. Firstly, if you want to concatenate `Strings` then use the string concatenation operator, not the addition operator. Also, NEVER concatenate two literals:

```vb
sqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=" & server & ";user id=" & username & ";password=" & password & ";database=" & database
```

The thing is, the reason you made this mistake in the first place is that concatenating lots of substrings that way makes your code hard to read and, therefore, error-prone. I would generally only use one concatenation operator or maybe two at the most. If you would need any more, use a different option. From .NET 1.0 to fairly recently, that option would  be `String.Format`:

```vb
sqlConn.ConnectionString = String.Format("server={0};user id={1};password={2};database={3}",
                                         server,
                                         username,
                                         password,
                                         database)
```

Much more readable and therefore not prone to the sort of errors you made. In more recent versions, you also have the option of string interpolation:

```vb
sqlConn.ConnectionString = $"server={server};user id={username};password={password};database={database}"
```

You shouldn't use any of those options though. As you're building a connection string, use the appropriate connection string builder. All ADO.NET providers have such a class and Connector/Net is no exception. I'm not sure what the specific properties would be called but it would look something like this:

```vb
Dim builder As New MySqlConnectionStringBuilder With {.Server = server,
                                                      .UserID = username,
                                                      .Password = password,
                                                      .Database = database}

sqlConn.ConnectionString = builder.ConnectionString
```

That is less error-prone still.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, it solved my problem

Comment: @LudemarLumasag, if an answer has resolved your problem then please accept it. That is how you show everyone that your question has been answered and you no longer need help with their having to open the question and read the whole thing. This is yet another example of why you should have taken the site tour when prompted and learned how to use this site properly.